# Слетела кодировка при переустановке WAMP. Как поправить?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Пришлось мне переустановить ОС на компьютере, соответственно пришлось заново устанавливать WAMP.
Клонировал с гитхаба репозиторий проекта, скормил в MySQL дамп БД, и теперь у меня на сайте вместо русских символов отображаются знаки вопроса(в смой бд всё норм). Хотя до переустановки всё работало исправно. В MySQL кодировка стоит utf8 - default collation
Как можно исправить сей косяк?

Comment: htaccess есть ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Ага, `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` там.

Comment: а в db тоже такая кодировка ? а сами файлы тоже в такой кодировке ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , в html  <meta charset="utf-8">. В db кодировка указана в вопросе: `utf8 - default collation`. Если из консоли mysql селекты делать, то все корректно отображается. С файлами думаю тоже все в порядке. Я же вчера еще работал с этим проектом, и запушил его на гитхаб. Все работало.

Comment: А как вы с БД работаете? PDO?

Comment: @Manitikyl, точно! Странно, но до переустановки PDO  корректно работало без явного указания `charset=utf8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы быть `100%` Уверенным что вы работаете с `UTF8` используя `PDO`:

**1 Способ**: Явно указать кодировку при подключении `;charset=utf8`:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=DB;host=HOST;charset=utf8';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
```

**2 Способ**: Через `options`:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
```

**P.S.** Тем кто любит легаси, и работает со старыми версиями, поможет прямой запрос:

```
$pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

**P.S.2.** Тем кто любит `MySQLi`, для вас существуют готовые функции:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
// или
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
```

(обратим внимание что `MySQLi` не знает что такое `utf-8`, пишем правильно)

**P.S.3.** Разъясним что куда:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'  // Меняет кодировку
SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'  // Задает набор символов
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci' // Для представления (для сравнения символов)
```

**Бонус**, расказываю лайфхак, можно делать так ;)

```
SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
```